# Is it possible send emails to joomla users from google calendar events

Tags: joomla, google-calendar-api

I have a google calendar and i have used Gcalndar extension to view events on my website.
Is it possible somehow that i can send the all joomla users an email about new events from google calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do it through Google Calendar unless you export a list of emails then paste that list in to the guests box in the event details. That would be a pretty big pain to do every time. It would probably be a lot easier to use one of the many newsletter management extensions to send out event announcements through the Joomla site. Tons of options in the JED here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter